# Avoid storing the whole message when signing with SPHINCS+

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

Unlike pretty much every other signature scheme that I am aware of (excluding Picnic, the original SPHINCS, and SPHINCS-gravity) SPHINCS+ requires that the whole message be available during the signing operation. This is because it uses a "message randomization value" which if I am not mistaken it is used in order to avoid multi-target attacks. From the SPHINCS+ reference implementation:

```
/* Compute the digest randomization value. */
gen_message_random(sig, sk_prf, optrand, m, mlen);

/* Derive the message digest and leaf index from R, PK and M. */
hash_message(mhash, &tree, &idx_leaf, sig, pk, m, mlen);
```

In order to bypass that requirement one could first hash the whole message and then sign the result but this means that the whole scheme will be broken if said hash function is not collision resistant (SPHINCS+ by itself only depends on the [second?] preimage resistance of the hash function).

My question is as follows: Is it possible to use "tree signing" (kinda like a merkle tree but for signatures) in order to avoid storing the whole message in memory and at the same time have the whole scheme depend only on the preimage resistance of the hash function?

The scheme that I have in mind would work as such (assuming that each node has exactly 2 children):
$$
\begin{align}
N_{i, 0} &= S_{sk}(0\| 0 \| i \| m_i) \\
N_{i, j + 1} &= S_{sk}(0\| j + 1 \| i \| N_{2i, j} \|N_{2i+1, j} ) \\
Sig &= S_{sk}(1 \| N_{0, J} \|N_{1, J})
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If I've understood your problem correctly; If you hash the message then you already read all of it, right?

Comment: Doesn't this always hold true?

Comment: Your proposal uses the function $S_{sk}$; is $sk$ a secret value (if so, how does the verification process work), or is it a public value (and if so, how does that not rely on collision resistance)?

Comment: sk is the private key for sphincs+. The verification process is the same but uses the public key instead. I should note that the tree nodes will be available to the one verifying.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to tag you: @kelalaka

Comment: and once more since only one user can be tagged per comment... @poncho

Comment: "The verification process is the same but uses the public key instead"; I'm not quite sure what you mean; what is the function $S$?  If you mean the verifier computes (for example) $S_{pk}(0||0||i||m_i)$, well, that has no obvious relation to the signature.  If instead you mean for $S_{sk}$ to mean the signature process (and by "the same", you mean that the verification process remains the same as in current Sphincs+), it's not clear how you avoid relying on collision resistance unless $S_{sk}$ itself has multiple passes over $m_i$

Comment: @poncho $S_{sk}$ is the signing, yes. The verifier would compute $V_{pk}(N_{i,0}, 0\|0\|i\|m_i)$, $V_{pk}(N_{i,j+1}, 0\|j+1\|i\|N_{2i,j}\|N_{2i+1,j})$, and $V_{pk}(Sig, 1\|N_{0,J}\|N_{1,J})$ - $V_{pk}$ in this case would be the verification process used in SPHINCS+ with pk as its public key. $S_{sk}$ is the SPHINCS+ signing process (with sk as its private key) and thus does have multiple passes over $m_i$.

Comment: But in Sphincs+, the end result of the verification process is the root node (which is compared to the root node value contained in the public key), so $V_{pk}(N_{i,0},0||0||i||m_{i} )$ would always be constant (assuming valid signatures)

Comment: @poncho Yes, this is done in order to verify that $N_{i,j}$ is a valid signature for $pk$. V returns true or false and we require all of the results to be true in order for the verification of the whole scheme to succeed.